# Convert a list comprehension loop into a regular for loop without creating an infinite loop

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert this list comprehension:

```
cfg = []
...
cfg = [conf + function1(s) for s in cfg]
```

To a regular multiline `for`, because it is necessary to include more things into it:

```
cfg = []
...
for s in cfg:
    cfg.append(conf + function1(s))
```

But in the second case, an infinite loop is created.

What is the equivalence for the list comprehension to a normal `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do two things:

- create a copy of `cfg` beforehand:

  ```
  for s in cfg[:]:
  ```
- or append to a *new* list and replace the old:

  ```
  new_cfg = []
  for s in cfg:
      new_cfg.append(...)

  cfg = new_cfg
  ```

The second option is the closest equivalent to the list comprehension, as it also creates a new list first before rebinding. The second option *replaces* the old `cfg` list values.

Your full `for` loop, however, is equivalent to the first option, since that option *preserves the old values* of `cfg`, appending new values. Your list comprehension never did this.

Comment: It works as expected, but only one notation. If you don't want duplicate entries in the first case, add a .remove(..) before .append(..). Thanks

Comment: @Rikr: or just not use the first case. Calling `.remove()` each time is not efficient when you just can clear the list.